# Extending django.contrib.auth module

Tags: python, django, authentication, module

I am an intermediate in django. But, I love to be an expert in that. I am going to create an open source application. To begin with I have planned to make use of contrib.auth module. I want to extend auth module within my application as user authentication. I am struckup with the basic things

- How do I include user authentication form within my application. Is there any {{form}} to print in my .html file?
- How can I reference my database table to user field in auth

I didn't designed my table yet. But want to extend it. Please some one contribute your ideas for creating an Open Source Application

-Vikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find everything you need in this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/). Happy reading!